# Working around for the `Cannot modify an immutable` in my subclass of Str?

Tags: raku

I have this class which subclasses `Str`:

```
use Vimwiki::File::TextProcessingClasses;
unit class Vimwiki::File::ContentStr is Str;

method new(Str:D $string) {
    self.Str::new(value => $string);
}

# this method fails
method capitalize-headers() {
    self = Vimwiki::File::TextProcessingClasses::HeadlineCapitalizer.new.capitalize-headers(self);
}
```

The problem is the `capitalize-headers` method fails with the `Cannot modify an immutable` error because it's a string. One way I could avoid this problem is to simply not subclass `Str` and write wrappers for the `Str` methods I want to use like this:

```
unit class Vimwiki::File::ContentStr;

has Str $!content;

method uc() {
   $!content = $!content.uc; 
}
```

But that got me wondering if instead of writing these wrapper method, there might be something like AUTOLOAD in Raku so that if a method does not exist, the non-existent method could default to being called on the `$!content` attribute.

Is this possible? Or is there a cleaner way around the immutable object problem?

Comment: Some more searching turned this up: https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-FALLBACK_(method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Str` type is immutable. When you write:

```
my $x = "string";
$x = "another string";
```

It works because `$x` is a `Scalar` container. You're not changing the `Str`, just arranging for `$x` to refer to a different `Str`. That `Str` is immutable is relied on all over the place in the Raku standard library, so even if you were to somehow create a mutable subclass, you're not in for a good time!

Further to that `self` is also always immutable. You can do this:

```
class SubStr is Str {
    method capitalize-inplace($self is rw:) {
        $self .= uc
    }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
my $x = SubStr.new(value => "hi");
$x.capitalize-inplace;
say $x
```

This is is, again, mutating the `Scalar` container `$x` and putting a new `SubStr` instance with the value `HI` into it. Thus this:

```
SubStr.new(value => "hi").capitalize-inplace
```

Will die:

```
Parameter '$self' expects a writable container (variable) as an
argument, but got 'hi' (SubStr) as a value without a container.
  in method capitalize-inplace at -e line 1
  in block <unit> at -e line 1
```

Thus if you want a mutable wrapper around `Str`, you'll really have to use composition, not inheritance.

> But that got me wondering if instead of writing these wrapper method, there might be something like AUTOLOAD in Raku so that if a method does not exist, the non-existent method could default to being called on the $!content attribute.

That's the [`FALLBACK` method](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-FALLBACK_(method)). (There's also [the `handles` trait](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-handles_trait-handles), but that's not quite what you want, as I imagine you wish to retain the wrapping.)

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's the code that does the job:

```
use Vimwiki::File::TextProcessingClasses;
unit class Vimwiki::File::ContentStr;

has Str $.content;

method FALLBACK ($name) {
    my $content = $!content;
    $content."$name"();
}

submethod BUILD (:$content) {
    $!content = $content;
};

method new( Str:D $content ) {
    self.bless( :$content );
}

method capitalize-headers() {
    $!content = Vimwiki::File::TextProcessingClasses::HeadlineCapitalizer.new.capitalize-headers($!content);
}
```